# The Web site {site name} does not exist

Tags: asp.net

So I have taken over an ASP site.

I have copied the solution directory to my local machine.

When I go to open the solution, 9 out of 10 of projects open fine except for the web project.

The following error is in the out put window

error  : Unable to open the Web site 'C:\Users\john.smith\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\xxx'.  'The Web site C:\Users\john.smith\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\xxx' does not exist.

Should this be the case?

Should the source sode need to refer to the websites directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In earler Visual Studio versions web sites have been split up into two directories. You need to copy the second directory as well, yes.

Comment: Interstingly enough when I download the project from TFS this issue is not present. There are others.

Comment: TFS is probably automatically giving you both directories. About the "other" issues: we can only help if you tell us which issues ;-)

Comment: TFS is not putting anything in the websites directory. It stands alone. The other issues are of a a lessor priority than this.