# Unable to open the Web site 'http://localhost/XYZ'. Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2019

I copied a web application to my local development machine. When I open the solution in Visual Studio 2019, I get the following error:

```
Unable to open the Web site 'http://localhost/XYZ'.  The Web site 'http://localhost/XYZ' does not 
exist. Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read.
```

I found this similar question and answer:

[The Web site {site name} does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819634/the-web-site-site-name-does-not-exist)

But the directory that is indicated in the error message is different. My error is specifically targeting "http://localhost/...". I've been developing with Visual Studio for several years and I've worked with IIS a little - configuring application pools and converting directories to websites - but that's about it. Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps to solve your problem：

1. Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
2. Click Programs and Features.
3. Click Turn Windows features on or off.
4. In the dialog box, expand Internet Information Services.
5. Expand Web Management Tools, and then expand IIS 6 Management
   Compatibility.
6. Click to select the IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration
   compatibility check box, and then click OK.
   [image]

Comment: It ended up opening just fine when I opened the containing folder as a Web Site. I'm not sure then why it still has a solution file?

Comment: Do you mean that after you publish, does the solution file still exist in the folder? How did you publish your application?